# cognitive vision library error : the remote server returned an error (401) in xamarin project

Tags: c#, xamarin, azure-cognitive-services

when I am trying to use cognitive vision library in xamarin project , I got an error message : the remote server returned an error (401)
I am using a VisionServiceClient object
this code is a code to analyze the picked picture .
I can't fix the error .
any advice , please ?

PS : is there is any problem in using free trial Api key ? this may be the cause of the error ? 
and should I have a credit card to create a cognitive vision resource instance in https://portal.azure.com/#home ?

this is the main_page code :

```
using Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision;
using Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision.Contract;
using Plugin.Connectivity;
using Plugin.Media;
using Plugin.Media.Abstractions;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ComputerVisionSample
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly VisionServiceClient visionClient;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.visionClient = 
                new VisionServiceClient("my_api_key");
        }
        private async Task<AnalysisResult> AnalyzePictureAsync(Stream inputFile)
        {
            if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Network error", 
                    "Please check your network connection and retry.", "OK");
                return null;
            }

            VisualFeature[] visualFeatures = new VisualFeature[] { VisualFeature.Adult,
                VisualFeature.Categories, VisualFeature.Color, VisualFeature.Description,
                VisualFeature.Faces, VisualFeature.ImageType, VisualFeature.Tags };

            AnalysisResult analysisResult = 
                await visionClient.AnalyzeImageAsync(inputFile, 
                visualFeatures);

            return analysisResult;            
        }

        private async void UploadPictureButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("No upload", "Picking a photo is not supported.", "OK");
                return;
            }

            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
            if (file == null)
                return;

            this.Indicator1.IsVisible = true;
            this.Indicator1.IsRunning = true;
            Image1.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => file.GetStream());

            try
            {
                this.BindingContext = await AnalyzePictureAsync(file.GetStream());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Indicator1.IsRunning = false;
                this.Indicator1.IsVisible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 401 is an Unauthorized error.  Check your authentication logic

Comment: Are you using `Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision.VisionServiceClient`? If so, you need to provide your API key as the first argument to the constructor.  A code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: @cthrash yes I am using this .

Comment: As noted above, a 401 error suggests an auth problem.  Make sure that your API key and regions match.  Can you check that?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094186/microsoft-cognitive-services-computer-vision-invalid-subscription-key/44123950#44123950 for more info

Comment: @cthrash  yes I think it matches , I have checked the link but when I did this : VisionServiceClient VisionServiceCliente = new VisionServiceClient(SubscriptionKey, StringOfMyURLTakedFromPortal); I got an error that VisionServiceClient  has no overload constructor with 2 parameters ,   and I couldn't reach this : " Go to portal.azure.com, in the dashboard of your subscription to the Cognitive Services > General Information > End Point take note of the URL. " thank you .

Comment: How old is the client library?  This is a deprecated library, but nevertheless there's been a two-arg constructor for quite some time now (https://github.com/microsoft/Cognitive-Vision-Windows/blob/05fc1d699b4162f348b0338dc3d963c86f43d90d/ClientLibrary/VisionServiceClient.cs#L131).  The current library is, incidentally, https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `401`, that means:

- you did not provide a subscription key
- or you provide one, but it is not matching the region where your resource is

You are using the default endpoint/region of `ComputerVision` by doing this:

```
this.visionClient = new VisionServiceClient("my_api_key");
```

And you are using an old package (`Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision` was the project codename).

So, you should do the following:

1 - Switch to the latest package called `Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision`, available on Nuget [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision)

2 - Create your client by doing the following:

```
var visionClient = new ComputerVisionClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials("yourAPIkeyHere")))
{
    Endpoint = "yourEndpointHere"
})
```

Endpoint format is: "https://region.api.cognitive.microsoft.com", for example for West Europe: "https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"

There may be some changes in the method you are calling or the parameters because of the package change, but you will now be up-to-date